# Issue with wix installer: jenkins auto-build

Tags: c#, jenkins, wix, wix3.5

I have 2 products A and B as part of one of our projects...for which we use a wix installer...the installer code is written in C# using visual studio 2008 and we've had no issues with building or using those installers.

Recently, we decided to implement an auto-build system (Jenkins) where we do an automated build of the products as well as the installers for them.

When we do the build from jenkins, the installer build for product A fails. It says - "The namespace "Deployment" does not exist in the Microsoft namespace".
and a bunch of other dependencies fail cos of this. Interestingly, this same build when done from visual studio on the same machine works...but fails when done via jenkins.

We are running all of this as an admin user. Not sure if jenkins is having issues accessing "Microsoft.Deployment"?

I tried reinstalling the wix framework (to make sure jenkins is not accessing some corrupted installer or deployment dll's) and added explicit references to "Microsoft.Deployment"...but did not help.

Also, the installer for the other product B which is also on the same machine runs without issues.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) installed with Visual Studio. That will automatically install DTF which sounds like the prerequisite you are missing in the Jenkins build. To get DTF, you can either install the WiX toolset on your build machines or, the better option IMHO, is to check the WiX toolset into source control. There is a topic in the WiX manual that provides step by step instructions called [Integrating WiX Projects Into Daily Builds](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/daily_builds.htm) to do the latter.

If you check-in the WiX toolset to your build, you may need to update some of existing references to point at the local copy of the WiX toolset.

Comment: No - I installed wix separately..not with visual studio. Also, I can see the Microsoft.Deployment dll in the SDK and bin folders in the wix install folder. Its stange why jenkins is unable to access it though.

Comment: Look at the `Reference` elements in the failing projects. They could have paths that aren't resolving quite right on the build machine.

Comment: well..I think I fixed it...I did the build using devenv instead of MSBuild and that kinda helped most of the problems.